# Can't connect to mongo lab on arduino yun

Tags: node.js, mongodb, arduino

I can't connect to a database with mongodb or mongoose on nodejs on my arduino yun.

```
Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error: { [MongoError: Authentication failed.]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Authentication failed.',
  ok: 0,
  code: 18,
  errmsg: 'Authentication failed.' }
```

I get that error. **The code works fine on my desktop computer.**

```
//lets require/import the mongodb native drivers.
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

//We need to work with "MongoClient" interface in order to connect to a mongodb server.
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// Connection URL. This is where your mongodb server is running.
var url = 'mongodb://*******:********@address:23118/arduino';

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
        //HURRAY!! We are connected. :)
        console.log('Connection established to', url);

        // do some work here with the database.

        //Close connection
        db.close();
    }
});
```

I am trying to connect to a mongo lab database. I have not tried connecting to any other database to troubleshoot. This is because I cannot find a free trial version where I do not need a credit card.

EDIT:

**I got an Object Rocket instance and it works perfectly on my arduino yun.** However it is very expensive; $30 a month (currently on the trial). And I don't need speed or lots of data. So if anyone could figure out why it doesnt work on mlab that would be great.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory in that the credentials given do not match an authorized account. My guess is the `arduino` database name here is different to what you have used before, and therefore this user is "not authorized" for that particular database. Correct the account to allow access to that database or create a new account for that database instead. It's not something people can "help you with". You need to fix the credentials.

Comment: @NeilLunn This would be the case, however the exact same URL and code works perfectly on my computer.

Comment: I bet that you do not. Either the account or password is not the same, or "most likely" the "database" portion of the URI is different. Authorization occurs "per database" and not "globally". Especially not with a mongolab account. Nothing for people to debug here other than point out those problem sources.

Comment: I copy and pasted the code from my computer. Looking at it now and there is no difference whatsoever. I'll try making a new database.

Comment: Sounding like a broken record here. *"We cannot help you with authentication issues"*. If it was a connection problem, then there are things to try, but that is not the case. "Authentication Failed" can only be solved by **you** or your **provider**. I just gave you the most common cause, which I still believe is correct but you just aren't listening or trying to copy/paste your URI again to spot the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experienced some authentication issues in the past and I've addressed them following the next steps:

1) Identify version numbers of both `mongo` server and `mongoose`

2) Identify what [authentication mechanism](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication-mechanisms/#security-authentication-mechanisms) does your server use and make sure that `mongoose` is trying to authenticate with the one your server is expecting. If you're using an old version, some authentication mechanism might not be supported, so you'd need to upgrade.

3) Identify where the user has been created. Check out [Authentication Database](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-users/#user-authentication-database) and make sure that your client is authenticating using such database. It can be different than the database you store your data. Indeed, it uses to be `admin`. If so, take a look to the [`authSource`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) option you can add to your connection string. More info [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Db.html).

In addition to all of the above, I'd recommend you to use the the `mongo` client to verify your credentials are right and you can connect to the database.

Comment: I haven't installed mongodb on my arduino yun. Could that be the problem? If so how would I get it? It's not available with opkg.\

Comment: I've assumed that the `address` you're trying to connect to is any host (either local or remote) where you have an instance of `mongod` up and running. You should test your environment is right before you start developing. It's obvious you can't connect to a service if it is not available.

Comment: Yes the address is a hosted instance everything on the cloud. I can connect to the address on my computer but not on my arduino.

Comment: As per the step 1 in my answer, what are those versions in both your computer and your Arduino? Have you try to connect using exactly the same procedure in both sides? Further, what are the results of both steps 2 and 3 in my answer?

Comment: 1. Yes its the same version because I am copying the module over from my computer to my arduino.

Comment: 2. & 3. Do you know how to download the mongo client onto the arduino yun?

Comment: It depends on the operative system you have. Find it and go to mongodb docs for instructions. Also, what is the version of mongo server?

Comment: I've briefly read some documentation of your Arduino Yun. They say it comes with a Linux distribution and offers a package manager called `opkg` (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunPackageManager). You need to use  it to find and install mongo-shell (https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/administration/install-on-linux/)

Comment: Opkg doesn't have mongo. That's why.

Comment: Ok I see. I'm such case just follow: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

Comment: Okay I looked at that. However I'm not sure whether the yun is 32bit or 64bit. `uname -m` outputted `mips` and on the website it says that the architecture is `MIPS @400MHz`

Comment: Okay so never mind about installing mongo. I got an Object Rocket instance working! I only have a thirty day trial, and would not like to pay. Any Ideas on why it would work on Object Rocket and not mlab?

Comment: This is another question. You are offering a bounty for help on Authentication issues, not for Object Rocket issues. In addition, you have never follow the steps I have instructed; I don't know what auth mechanism are you using nor the auth database yet. :/

Comment: Sorry. What I meant is that switching to a different mongo hosted fixed my problem. I want to know why.

Comment: You want to know why and my answer is pointing you to "Authentication mechanisms" and "Authentication database", see steps 2 and 3 respectively. These can be the source of the problem you have reported but you tend to work them around.